# Jade: Interpolation not work in included block from separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I try to separate my .jade templates if they were regular html with Handlebars.  I trying to keep the original HTML structure. So far this worked, until I tried to separate my header into a different file.

*./views/layouts/main.jade*

```
block header
  include ../partials/layout-top.jade
| 
block content
| 
| 
|<script src="/javascripts/plugins.js"></script>
|<script src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
| 
|</body>
|</html>
|
```

*./views/partials/layout-top.jade*:

```
block header
  |<!doctype html>
  |<html class="no-js" lang="">
  |<head>
  |  <meta charset="utf-8">
  |  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  |  <title>My title</title>
  |  <meta name="description" content="#{description}">
  |  <meta name="keywords" content="#{keywords}">
  |  <meta name="author" content="info@domain.com">
  |  <meta name="generator" content="Static pages built on Node.js, Express.js, Markdown, Jade">
  |  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  |  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  |  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  |  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  |  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style-helper.css">
  |</head>
  |<body class="#{bodyClass}">
```

*./views/portfolio.jade*:

```
extends ./layouts/main

block content
  |<h1>#{title}</h1>
  |<p>Welcome to #{title}</p>
```

*./views/error.jade*:

```
extends ./layouts/main

block content
  |<h1>#{message}</h1>
  |<h2>#{error.status}</h2>
  |<pre>#{error.stack}</pre>
```

This solution not work. The layout-top.jade file will be rendered, but the interpolated values like `#{description}` `#{keywords}` not be shown (only empty space between `""`).

Someone can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason your using that much HTML in a jade template? Seems to defeat the purpose of using Jade. Also why all the pipes? As for what it doesn't work. Are you sure descriptiona and keywords are even being passed? What's the express look like?

Comment: The reason was that all of the sample codes used `foreach ... in ...` methods to implement loops and that time when I asked this question I didn't know how to done this with Handlebars. But I wanted to keep the original HTML structure. Now I happy with Handlebars and I don't use Jade. The simplified look of Jade for me is just messy. Apples and oranges.

Comment: Please consider deleting this unanswered question that also uses Jade/Pug in a completely non-standard way and is prone to errors.  I'm glad you found a template engine that meets your way of working :)

Comment: If you do want to keep this question alive please post the route code that calls this template, as that's where the core issue with this lies (not in the pug code).

Comment: This project abandoned long ago.